# codeigniter linking to another page

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am new to codeigniter framework. i am having problem with href link. in my home page i have some menu, that goes to different page. for example in normal php if i want to go Sell Books page then i just put sellBook.php in href link. now in codeigniter how can i do this. do i need write something in controller ?

```
<li ><a href="http://www.studenthint.com/">Home </a> </li>
<li><a href="">Buy Books</a> </li>
<li><a href="sellBook.php">Sell Books</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Books on Demand</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Request a Book</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a> </li>
```

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 6):

as per MVC pattern each of your url is a controller so:

if you, for example, want to link to

```
http://www.site.com/users
```

so the controller will look like:

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{
  function index(){
  //do somenthing here
  }
  function list(){
  //list your users
 }
}
```

then in your views linking to that controller is simple:

```
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('users'); ?>">this will link to your users controller and index() method</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('users/list'); ?>">this will link to your users controller and list() method</a>
```

> the site_url(); method will helps you finding the right link both if
>   you are using index.php or not in your urls

Comment: @sbaaaaang:  In Hindi Language, I Say "Umda". Means, Very Good.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>controller_name/function_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the `index.php` from the URL, you can write your URL as `href="/sellbook"` otherwise you will have to include it, such as `href="/index.php/sellbook"`.

This assumes, of course, that you have a properly configured route name `sellbook`. See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html for details on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If the links are to other pages on your site, then I think your best bet will be to use the url helper, assuming you're using the standard seo friendly format and not query strings.  This way, you don't have to take into consideration whether you'll be using .htaccess or not.  For example:

```
echo anchor('your_controller_name/your_function_name/param_1/param_2', 'Sell Books', 'title="Sell Books"');
// or for your home page
echo anchor('/', 'Home', "title='Home'");
```

If it's an external link, you can use the same function or just a plain html tag:

```
echo anchor('http://google.com', 'Google Me', 'title="Google Me"');
// OR
<a href="http://google.com" title="Google Me" >Google Me</a>
```

Note: make sure you load your url_helper in your controller if you'll be using the anchor function:

```
$this->load->helper('url')
// or add to autoload.php
```

You can also do it the way @sbaaaang suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('Customer/Settings');?>">Account Details</a>
```

You can use like this

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/') . 'controller_name/function_name' ?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/') . 'controller_name/function_name' ?>">Buy Books</a> </li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/') . 'controller_name/function_name' ?>">Sell Books</a> </li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/') . 'controller_name/function_name' ?>">Books on Demand</a> </li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/') . 'controller_name/function_name' ?>">Request a Book</a> </li>
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/') . 'controller_name/function_name' ?>">About Us</a> </li>
```

Answer (score -1):

//use
`site_url` in link with controller name and method
and

```
$this->load->view('page_name');
```