# how to link another page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
```

In my menubar there is home ,about, contact, client ext.list are available.
        i want give a      link for open those related page.
        so please tell me how i write a controller file code to link those page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205155/codeigniter-correct-way-to-link-to-another-page-in-a-view

Answer (score 0):

You must make some change in the controller and link your views to the controller..It is simple.

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387975/codeigniter-linking-to-another-page)

Comment: **localhost/projectname/index.php/controllerfilename/controllerfinctionname thanku sir for ur support**