# CodeIgniter link routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am new in CodeIgniter. How to give a link to next page like HTML in codeigniter.In HTML we use `<a href="page link">page name</a>`. How to do this thing in codeigniter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('controller_name');?>">Some Name</a> 

<a href="<?php echo base_url('subfolder/controller_name');?>">Some Name</a>
```

I would use `base_url()` for view files when linking or `anchor()`;

```
anchor('controller_name', 'Some Name');

anchor('subfolder/controller_name', 'Some Name');
```

Auto-load the [URL helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

You may need to set custom routes for controller [Routing In Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

CI2 & CI3 User Doc's Here. [Codeigniter Docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs)

Answer (score 2):

Goto `application >> config >> autoload.php`

change line

```
$autoload['helper'] = array("url");
```

and change link to

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controllername/functionname');?>">MyLink</a>
```

*'controllername'* should be your desired controller name and *'functionname'* the same as desired!

Answer (score 0):

You can try so-

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/function/uri') ?>">Link</a>
```

[CodeIgniter - Correct way to link to another page in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205155/codeigniter-correct-way-to-link-to-another-page-in-a-view)

[codeigniter linking to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387975/codeigniter-linking-to-another-page)

Comment: That's old user guide link CI2 & CI3 guides here now http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: Ohh ok..thanx for the info :)